# Flink Table API Condition in Select Clauses

Tags: apache-flink

A related old mailing list: [link](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/Conditional-branching-in-Table-API-td15715.html)

Flink Table API Conditional Function Documentation: [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/functions/systemFunctions.html#conditional-functions)

Example:

```
table.select($("apple").isNotNull()
                ? $("apple").as("fruit")
                : $("pear").as("fruit"));
```

$("apple").isNotNull() returns an ApiExpression not Boolean.

Anyone has tried similar things with Table API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Table API you are just constructing an expression that will be executed later. So all expressions just return another expression and thus construct a tree of expressions. Use `org.apache.flink.table.api.Expressions#ifThenElse` or `CASE WHEN END` in SQL.